# I am trying to take input from a json body and want to validate if all the inputs are correct if not through exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I have a class in which a method does simple calculation, accepts two numbers and give addition.Now i want to pass the numbers through api in json format and validate if the inputs are numbers if not through excpetions.

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/TC")
    public class CountSpringAppController {

    @Autowired
    private CountService countService;

    @PostMapping(value="/add/{number1}/{number2}") 
    public int getCount(@PathVariable int num1,@PathVariable int num2) {

        return countService.count(num1, num2);
    }

    @Service
    public class CountService {

        public int count(int num1, int num2) {
            if (num1==null) {
                return; //exception
            }
            return num1+num2;     
        }
    }
```

> exception class

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @ExceptionHandler(value= {Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAnyException(Exception 
    ex,WebRequest request){
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(ex,new 
    HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }
```

have response class with the required variables and getter and setter method

```
 input
 {
   num1="",
   num2=2
 }

 output 
 {
   error code:404
   message: "number cannot be null"
   ststus :"Fail"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
Class ApiRequestBody {
    private Integer num1;
    private Integer num2;

    public ApiRequestBody(Integer num1, Integer num2){
        num1 = num1;
        num2 = num2;
    }
    // Rest of getter and setters
}

@PostMapping(value="/add") 
public int getCount(@RequestBody ApiRequestBody request) {
    return countService.count(request.getNum1(), request.getNum2());
}


@Service
public class CountService throws Exception{
    public int count(Integer num1, Integer num2) {
    if(num1==null || num2 ==  null){
        throw new Exception("Number cannot be null");
    }
    return num1+num2;     
}
```

Create a new class for response :

```
Class ApiResponse {
private int errorCode;
private String message;
private String status;

public ApiResponse(Exception e){
    errorCode = 400;
    message = e.getMessage();
    status = "Fail";
}
// Rest of the getter and setters
}
```

And then in your controller Advice :

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value= {Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> handleAnyException(Exception ex,WebRequest request){
        ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse(ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response,new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

This is just a sample. It can be done in better ways obviously like creating your own custom exception class, throwing that exception, catching that particular exception in Controller Advice, creating a correct response like Appropriate response code, message and returning it. But i am just giving you can idea how it can be done.

Comment: an int never will be null, if you cast a Integer to int and the Integer is null it throw an Null Pointer Exception in you method call :)

Comment: The question was to get input from JSON. I can't find an answer to the question in your code. "Now i want to pass the numbers through api in json format and validate if the inputs are numbers if not through excpetions."

Comment: Hi @Vusal, I have added the solution for receiving a JSON request also. Hope now answer is more complete

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it in controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/add/{number1}/{number2}") 
public int getCount(@PathVariable @NotNull Integer num1,@PathVariable @NotNull Integer num2) {
    return countService.count(num1, num2);
}
```

It will throw `NullPointerException` the input is not integer.

Now you should catch the exaption and return your object

```
@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
public ResponseEntity<*JSON*> handleNullPointerException() {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.*Status*).body(*JSON*);
}
```

Just edit *JSON* to your object and *Status* to http status.

Comment: The question was to get input from JSON. I can't find an answer to the question in your code. "Now i want to pass the numbers through api in json format and validate if the inputs are numbers if not through excpetions."

Comment: i explain it, you can catch the exception and return a json (object)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the input parameters from JSON - then you probably should (but it's not mandatory, there are other ways to get a JSON from a client) get them from HTTP Requests body, but in your code - you expect parameters from the path.

You have to create a model class, for example:

```
class SumModel {
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    // getters & setters were omitted
}
```

Then you can retrieve an object of `SumModel`, which passed as an HTTP Requests body using the next code:

```
@PostMapping(value="/add") 
public int getCount(@RequestBody SumModel model) {
    return countService.count(model);
}
```

And your service would look like:

```
@Service
public class CountService throws Exception{
    public int count(SumModel model) {
        return model.getNum1() + model.getNum2();     
    }
}
```

If the `num1` or `num2` were not numbers - then the `JsonProcessingException` will be thrown - and you will catch it in your `ExceptionHandlerAdvice`.

You can also apply some [bean validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) annotations or create custom ones - for `SumModel` class.

If you wish to get JSON from some `@PathVariable` then you have to create custom `DataBinder` for your type.

Answer (score 0):

A way (not absolute, and it might differ from use-case to use-case) to do this is by creating a corresponding entity representing the expected JSON body.

In my example, I want to fetch all students of a specific class (the literal class) who stay in a specified area. And the following would be my expected:

```
{     
    "addressPincode": AU1100,
    "classCode": 201
}
```

This can easily mapped to a corresponding request class, which will look as following.

```
public class StudentRequest {
    String addressPincode;
    Integer classCode;
}
```

In my controller class, I would add an annotation `@Valid` which would insure that all the inputs are of the specified data types or not.

```
public Class StudentController {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getStudents(@Valid @RequestBody StudentRequest studentRequest) {
        // do something
    }
}
```